# How to create multiple objects from a class with different variables?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, processing

I have a class called `Rain`. It has a constructor in it and various methods. In my program I want to be able to generate say 50 objects, but I want them to have different values along the x-axis. I have 2 objects done and they slide down the area but I want to be able to create 50 plus of these so I can achieve the effect of rain. Basically here is my code and my constructors.

Rain Program:

```
Rain rain;
Rain rain2;

void setup()
{
    size (400,400);
    noStroke();
    rain = new Rain(20,random(0,10),3,15);
    rain2 = new Rain(random(15,35), random(70,110),3,15);
}

void draw()
{
    background(0);
    rain.colour(125,155,100);
    rain.display();
    rain2.colour(125,155,100);
    rain2.display();
}
```

And here is the class itself:

```
class Rain
{
    float wCoord, xCoord, yCoord, zCoord;
    int red, green, blue, gray;

    Rain()
    {
    }

    Rain(float wCoord, float xCoord, float yCoord, float zCoord)
    {
        this.wCoord = wCoord;
        this.xCoord = xCoord;
        this.yCoord = yCoord;
        this.zCoord= zCoord;
    }

    void display()
    {
        rect(20,xCoord, yCoord, zCoord);
        xCoord+=3;
        if(xCoord>height-5)
            {
                xCoord=random(0,15);
            }
    }

    void colour(int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
        fill (red, green, blue);
    }

    void colour(int gray){
        this.gray = gray;
        fill (this.gray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025881/how-to-create-array-from-a-class-constuctor) already includes explanations on how to create multiple instances using an `array` or `ArrayList`. What exactly are you confused about? Can you post an image showing the effect you're going for?

Comment: Can you indent your code sensibly please?

Comment: what do you do with Rain() ?  It just seems useless.

Comment: where come your random() from ?

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina `random()` is a method provideded by [Processing](http://processing.org)'s API

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in the code.

*see the comments*

```java
//an array of Rains... shouldn't it be called Drop
Rain[] drops = new Rain [1000];

void setup()
{
  size (400, 400);

  // initialize all Rains
  // the constructor gets no parmeters
  // and random initialization is handled
  // at class itself
  for (int i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
    drops[i] = new Rain();
  }
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);

  // just diaplay them
  for (Rain r : drops) {
    r.display();
  }
}


//any key to demosntrate colour() method
void keyPressed() {
  for (Rain r : drops) {
    r.colour(255);
  }
}

// and the overload version
void keyReleased() {
  for (Rain r : drops) {
    r.colour(125, 155, 100);
  }
}



class Rain
{    
  // you never used wcoord... got rid
  // renamed some vars to make code easier to read
  // like now the coord used to y position is 
  // yCoord instead of xCoord... :)
  // variables with meaningfull names rules

  float xCoord, yCoord, w, h, speed;

  // a default color
  color c = color(125, 155, 100);

  final static int MIN_Y      = -200, MAX_Y = 0;
  final static int MIN_WIDTH  = 2, MAX_WIDTH = 4;
  final static int MIN_HEIGHT = 5, MAX_HEIGHT = 13;
  final static int MIN_SPEED  = 2, MAX_SPEED = 6;

  Rain()
  {
    //Get new random values
    initialize();
  }


  void initialize() {
    yCoord = random(MIN_Y, MAX_Y);
    xCoord = random(width);
    w      = random(MIN_WIDTH, MAX_WIDTH);
    h      = random(MIN_HEIGHT, MAX_HEIGHT);
    speed  = random(MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED);
  }

  void display()
  {
    noStroke();
    fill(c);
    rect(xCoord, yCoord, w, h);

    yCoord+=speed;

    if (yCoord > height-5)
    {
      initialize();
    }
  }

  void colour(int red, int green, int blue)
  {

    c = color (red, green, blue);
  }

  void colour(color gray) {
    c = color (gray);
  }
}
```